# How to monitor https traffic using packetbeat?

Tags: linux, elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elastic-beats, packetbeat

Is there way to get the response code of https calls using packetbeat. I don’t see any protocol for https. The goal is to monitor https traffic

Answer (score 0):

With elastic agent [Network Packet Capture](https://docs.elastic.co/integrations/network_traffic) or Packetbeat you can capture (sniff) and analyze network traffic from a host.

I tried with `HTTP` and `HTTPS` traffic and both of them are working fine. You can even collect the body with `HTTP`.

For `HTTPS` you can only capture the headers.

Another recommendation: **PROXY**

Also, you can use a proxy like NGINX, or HaProxy to monitor requests or you can use packetbeat or Elastic agent to collect them.

Comment: Which protocol you used to monitor https traffic?

Comment: I used the HTTP protocol to monitor HTTPS traffic

Comment: Shouldn’t we use tls? Documentation says http protocol is to monitor only http traffic

Comment: https://docs.elastic.co/en/integrations/network_traffic#tls

yes you can use TLS, it would be much more make sense.

Comment: I tried with both tls and http protocol. I could not see headers of https traffic